# MySQL Fulltext searching and minimum search term length

Tags: mysql, file, full-text-search

I am using fulltext searching in mysql to search a database of videos I have, however when I search my videos some results will never get returned because the title I am searching for is less than the ft_min_word_len set in MySQL's settings.

```
mysql_query("SELECT MATCH(videoDescription) AGAINST('".$searchString."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
               FROM videos 
              LIMIT ".$start.",".$end."");
```

I tried firing up the mysql console to change the setting, however it told me it is read only. The only possible solution I have seen is to have the setting overridden at startup with option files. How do I use option files to overwrite the ft_min_word_len to 2 at startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`ft_min_word_len`** is a system variable, that has to be set at the startup of the MySQL server.

This can be done passing parameters on the command-line used to start MySQL, or *(recommended, I'd say)*, using a file containing options -- generally, for example, something like `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` should do the trick.

For more informations about setting system variables, you can take a look at the following section of the manual :

- [4.2.3. Specifying Program Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/program-options.html)

Also, don't forget that you'll have to rebuild your fulltext index, after changing that parameter, so the new value is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks, I know about having to rebuild the fulltext index. The documentation just looked a little thick to me, do I simply edit my.cnf and add the line ft_min_word_len = 2?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Comment: If anything I'm not sure which [group] this option falls under.

Comment: `[mysqld]`. `2` is a bit ambitious!

Comment: @AFK : considering it's related to the server, I would place it in a `[mysqld]` section ; that's also what's done in the example given on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html