# Issue with Singular Words and MySQL Fulltext Searching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I've setup a fulltext search to listen on the title and description columns for my blog articles table in MySQL. The SQL that I use to search the table is as follows:

> SELECT title,description,publish_date FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('cats','dogs') ORDER BY publish_date DESC LIMIT 100

This works (for 'dogs' and 'cats'), but when I use the singular ('dog' or 'cat') then I find no results. Not sure why this is going on, I've tried different variations like "+dog, +cat" and tried including IN BOOLEAN MODE as well ... Nothing works. And Yes I am sure that there are other words in the description column that are "dog" and "cat" as well as their plural versions.

How can I get singular words to work with MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default minimum word length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) for full-text searches is 4 characters.

You'll need to change that in the server configuration. See h[ere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239962/mysql-fulltext-searching-and-minimum-search-term-length) for some info  on how to do it.

Comment: Great! Is there anyway to get around the minimum length issue within the SQL query or CREATE syntax for the index? I do not have access to the my.conf file nor any global query configuration setting privileges with my host.

Comment: @matsko  I would look through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=workaround+ft_min_word_len whether any workarounds exist (but I'm afraid it doesn't look like they do)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something like this:

```
SELECT title,description,publish_date, MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('search') AS score  FROM table WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('seacrh') ORDER BY score LIMIT 100;
```

maybe this will help but will not work propertly with one word

Comment: How does this address the minimum word length problem? I don't understand.

Comment: the thing here is that you have to introduce on 'search' the full text you're searching exmpel 'cat dog' not 'cat''dog' and the query will search all the words on the fulltext index that you created in this case over title & description and order results by relevance. But, I never evaluated the performance as long as I only used this in small databases more less 10.000 rows